# Pretty printing R function

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I am working on some text with embedded R code.  I am using Sweave to produce PDF documents.  I'd like to print the functions as written into my PDF, but `print(f)` where *f* is an arbitrary function eliminates some of the key aspects, like the function name.  For instance:

```
f <- function(x, y = 2) {
  return(x^y)
}

print(f)
```

yields this:

```
> source('~/.active-rstudio-document')
function(x, y = 2) {
  return(x^y)
}
```

Is there some version of `print` or some similar function that would print something I can cut and paste directly back into R, preserving the function declaration (the `f <-` part)?  Also, and this is kind of an after thought, is there a way to set the maximum width in characters?

Comment: I’m not a Sweave user but are you sure that Sweave doesn’t offer a direct way of displaying the R source code? I know other processors (Knitr, rmarkdown) do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's probably a better way but something like this would work:

```
f <- function(x, y = 2) {
  return(x^y)
}

pretty <- function(fun){
    captured <- capture.output(fun)
    captured[1] <- paste(as.character(substitute(fun)), "<-", captured[1])

    cat(paste(captured, collapse="\n"))
}

pretty(f)

## f <- function(x, y = 2) {
##   return(x^y)
## }
```

Comment: Indeed not a bad way. Two caveats to this: (1) depending on how the source was loaded, this either preserves the source’s original formatting or re-formats the source code (`source` option `keep.source`). (2) It presumes that `<-` was used to assign the function (instead of, say, `=`, `<<-` or even `assign`). Not a problem per se, but worth keeping in mind.

Comment: In this case, those are two caveats I may be willing to accept, but I haven't had a chance to test the proposed solution yet.